# Spark RDD mapping questions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text data as below

```
no1      1|3|4
no2      4|5|6
```

and I want to transform the above data as below using spark RDD and scala language.

```
no1      1
no1      3
no1      4
no2      4
no2      5
no2      6
```

I am very new to Spark and Scala. And I can't find any example that does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to read in the file as data frame, whose API will be put more emphasis on in the future spark version than RDD API. And with a data frame, the task you are asking is fairly straightforward with `split` and `explode` functions:

```
val df = Seq(("no1", "1|3|4"), ("no2", "4|5|6")).toDF("A", "B")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: string, B: string]

df.show
+---+-----+
|  A|    B|
+---+-----+
|no1|1|3|4|
|no2|4|5|6|
+---+-----+


df.withColumn("B", explode(split($"B", "\\|"))).show
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|no1|  1|
|no1|  3|
|no1|  4|
|no2|  4|
|no2|  5|
|no2|  6|
+---+---+
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. If I have a data txt file and want to have it inputted (not manually typing), how to achieve command for user-inputted file?

Comment: @sclee1 by learning Spark. I'm not being snide, it's just you cannot expect to write your application only from a sequence of questions to [SO]. Any Spark tutorial will cover reading from a file.

Comment: Depending on your spark version the reading from a file will be different. For spark 2+, I find `spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv(your file)` to be convenient to use.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have your input in a file called inputFile.txt.

1. Read the File

   ```
   >>>inputRDD = sc.textFile("Documents/SparkPractice/inputFile.txt")
   ```
2. The file will be read as:

   ```
   >>>inputRDD.collect()
   ```

*['no1 1|3|4', 'no2 4|5|6']*

3. Now, first split each line,i.e. 'no1 1|3|4' and 'no2 4|5|6' according to the space.

   ```
   >>> rdd1 = inputRDD.map(lambda x: x.split(' '))
   >>> rdd1.collect()
   ```

*[['no1', '1|3|4'], ['no2', '4|5|6']]*

4. Now, we need to split '1|3|4' and '4|5|6'. rdd1 has two indexes in each element(like no1 and 1|3|4, no2 and 4|5|6).
   Iterate over each element of rdd1 using lambda and in each element, concatenate x[0]=no1,a space and x[1].split('|')=[1,3,4] using list comprehension. Similary, concatenate the second element x[0]=no2, a space and x[1].split('|')=[4,5,6].

   ```
    rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x: [x[0]+' '+y  for y in x[1].split('|')])
    rdd2.collect()
   ```

*[['no1 1', 'no1 3', 'no1 4'], ['no2 4', 'no2 5', 'no2 6']]*

5. Finally, flatten the rdd2. FlatMap will collapse all lists and put them in a single list:

   ```
    rdd3 = rdd2.flatMap(lambda x: x)
    rdd3.collect()
   ```

*['no1 1', 'no1 3', 'no1 4', 'no2 4', 'no2 5', 'no2 6']*

6. You can finally combine all these steps as:

   ```
     rdd1 = inputRDD.map(lambda x: x.split(' ')).flatMap(lambda x: [x[0]+' '+y  for y in x[1].split('|')])
   ```
7. Save this in your output file by collapsing all partitions to a single partition:

   ```
    rdd1.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("Documents/SparkPractice/outputFile")
   ```

Hope that my answer helps you!

Answer (score 0):

We can read text file and simply use rdd transformations for your solution

```
val rrd=spark.sparkContext.textFile("file_path").map(x=>x.split("\t")).map(x=>(x.head,x.last))
val trdd=rdd.map{case(k,v)=> v.split("\\|").map((k,_))}
trdd.collect.foreach(x=>x.foreach(x=>println(x._1+"\t"+x._2)))


o/p looks like 
no1 1
no1 3
no1 4
no2 4
no2 5
no2 6
```